# How do I make my programs independent of local libraries, and execute on another machine?

Tags: c

I compiled a c program which uses openssl, when I tried to run the executable file on other machine, I got some error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This may be caused by the old version of openssl on the machine where I run the executable file. It is complicated if I should install the right version of openssl where I run the program.
How to get rid of this dependence?

Comment: you get rid of the dependency by linking it statically instead of dynamically

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: command the linker to link it statically.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if I want to do that in c++?

Comment: You can tell the linker to [statically link a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578484/telling-gcc-directly-to-link-a-library-statically). Linking is essentially the same for all languages compiled languages (including C/C++): the linker takes all object files and creates the object code for your software, which will then be assembled by the assembler. You need to find your linker settings and update those.

Comment: You can make an appimage https://stackoverflow.com/q/69319186/1216776